# Laravel 7 post and get different key to common key

Tags: laravel

I hope, I could express myself well. I want to create common key for user id without middleware.

```
GET: Route::get('/users/edit/{id},'UserController@edit')->('users.edit')->middleware('permission:edit_user');

POST: Route::post('/users/edit','UserController@update')->('users.update')->middleware('permission:edit_user');
```

Now, when I check the user id from ***get request*** just use this; `$request->id` but in ***post request*** it's `$request->user_id` not id.

In middleware just use this code: `$user = User::where('id', request->id);` without using ***if else***.

How can I get this key to common just for id ? It's should be like this scenario (get: id, post: user_id)

Could be Service Container and Service Provider ? How can I use services ?

Thanks.

Comment: You should add the update and edit methods code because I don’t have an idea of what are you trying to do and why you can’t use the same key in both methods

Comment: actually because i don't want change user group settings. in post request id using by group id. it's little complicated :(

Comment: So why you don’t want to use the if else in the middleware? Seems that a variable with is_empty(request—>id) ?: request->user_id should solve the problem? Again I’m not sure what are you trying to solve and in which point of the code your problem is. Is it at the middleware, in the controller?

Comment: I'll try your suggestion, thanks